# Condicional if php no funciona

Tags: php, html5, mysqli, condiciones

Estoy consultando registros de una base de datos, busco imprimir todos los resultados de la tabla si es que los hay, cuando la tabla está vacía quiero que imprima un mensaje de que no existen registros, esta es mi condicional del Query:

```
$consultaPublicaciones = mysqli_query($conexion, $queryPublicaciones);
if (!empty($consultaPublicaciones)) {
    $res = true;
} else{
    $res = false;
}
```

al momento de imprimir funciona ya que encuentra registros, pero al borrarlos y dejar la tabla vacía se supone que debe proceder al else, pero no imprime nada:

```
<?php if($res){ ?>
                <?php while($resPublicaciones = mysqli_fetch_array($consultaPublicaciones)) { ?>
                    <div class="contenido">
                        <header class="public_nombre"><?= $resPublicaciones['nombre'], " ", $resPublicaciones['apellido']?></header>
                        <p class="public_descrip"><i class="icono fa fa-paw"></i><?= $resPublicaciones['descripcion']?></p>
                        <?php echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $resPublicaciones['foto'] ).'" class="img_public">'?>
                    </div>
                <?php } ?>
            <?php } else{ echo "No hay publicaciones";} ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Cambia tu `if` ya que estas checaando si no esta vacia y puede ser que te este regresando un false

Ejemplo:

```
<?php
$consultaPublicaciones = mysqli_query($conexion, $queryPublicaciones);
if ($consultaPublicaciones)
{
    if(mysqli_num_rows($consultaPublicaciones)>0)
    {
        while($resPublicaciones = mysqli_fetch_array($consultaPublicaciones)) 
        { 
            echo '<div class="contenido">
                <header class="public_nombre">'.$resPublicaciones['nombre'].' '.$resPublicaciones['apellido'].'</header>
                <p class="public_descrip"><i class="icono fa fa-paw"></i>'. $resPublicaciones['descripcion'].'</p>
                <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($resPublicaciones['foto']).'" class="img_public">
            </div>';
        }
    }
    else{
        echo "No hay publicaciones";
    }
} 
else{//si ocurrio un error regresa false
    echo "error: ".mysqli_error($conexion);
}
?>
```

Comment: Ya apliqué los cambios y sigue sin funcionar, incluso si meto el elseif con la condición específica no lo hace